# Unable to flush buffer data to disk when using FFmpeg and avio library to write a mp4 video file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to create a mp4 file from screenshots and it works fine. But I want to flush the video to disk every 30 seconds so that in the case of program crash I don't lose everything. I tried to use `avio_flush` method, but the problem is I have `avformat_write_header(AVFormatContext* s)` methos at the initialization and if I don't close it using `av_write_trailer(AVFormatContext* s)` it doesn't save the video correctly. If I close and reopen it, only the first portion gets saved (even if file size increases). I tried everything I could think of but I am stuck.

Update: Using the .h264 extension as suggested by @Nejat resolved the problem, but using this extension, I don't have the timestamps in the output video. Here is the part of my code to initialize packet pts and duration:

```
    AV_TIME_BASE;
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = nullptr;
    pkt.size = 0;
    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    pkt.pts -= first_pts;
    pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, cctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
    pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts, cctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
    pkt.dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;

    if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
        static int counter = 0;
        if (counter == 0) {
            first_pts = pkt.pts;
            pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pkt.pts, cctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
        }

        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, &pkt) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write frame\n");
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this use-case you could use MKV container instead of MP4. MKV does not need the `av_write_trailer` to be called for being valid. When you record on MKV containers, you could watch the video on the fly while the file is still open and you are writing to it. So in case of a crash you don't miss anything that has been written to video file.

Comment: Thank you very much Nejat. With MKV it didn't work, but using h264 it worked like you suggested. The only problem is, using this extension it doesn't register timestamps (video starts from 00:00 and ends 00.00) even if I close the trailer.

Comment: @Hamed Maybe that's because of wrong pts values. Do you rescale pts values to output timebase using functions like `av_rescale_q_rnd`?

Comment: No I haven't used any function to rescale pts values, but the timestamps were fine with mp4 extension. I am new to ffmpeg and I don't know how to do it, just copied an example and tweaked it a bit.

Comment: Input stream and output (the one writing to file) may have different timebase. You should rescale `pts` and `duration` values of packets to output timebase using `av_rescale_q`. All `dts` values could be `AV_NOPTS_VALUE`. Also make sure output pts values start from zero: `packet->pts = packet->pts - first_pts` to have proper video file duration.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nejat. I will try this.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but still no timestamps! I add the code below the original question.

Comment: My suggestion was considering that you have packets and want to write to a video file. The code you provided shows that you have frames, encode them and write to file. In this case your frames should have proper pts values or at least you should provide proper ones based on timebase and then use `av_rescale_q`. Or make proper pts values based on timbase of output stream before calling `av_interleaved_write_frame`. Also in the code you provided, you should first encode using `avcodec_receive_packet` and then modify pts values.

Comment: @Hamed So have you solved your problem? I'm coming to this problem either. My ffmpeg on iOS APP, muxing mp4 costs a lot of memory. Could you give me some help? thx